# How to make work on submit function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick, onsubmit

Ayo,

I'm a bit struggling with functions in JS.
The idea is that after the user clicks submit button, it checks if all the required fields have been filled out and if yes, it will trigger the loading animation.
The loading animation is supposed to be a status indicator in the meanwhile of sending the form and redirection to the success page.

I tried to use the onsubmit function in the form HTML tag but that does not work. The important thing  is that it will happen one if the required fields are filled out.

Thanks

JS

```
const submit_btn = document.querySelector('.submit-btn')

function loading() {
  this.innerHTML = "<div class='loader'></div>"
}
```

HTML

```
<form
  onsubmit="loading()" 
  action="https://formsubmit.co/2007080c2cf8bd2ebb68506e7aa98c5f"
  method="POST"
  enctype="multipart/form-data"
>
```

I tried to use the onsubmit function in the form HTML tag but that does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regards to *validation*:

You can use the `Constrained Validation API` (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Constraint_validation)) to check if all fields have been filled. Usually you want to use it *after* the user has submitted the `<form>` but *before* the form is sent to the server.

This is achievable by using it inside an event handler that is called on `submit`ting the form.

In regards to *event handling*:

To implement the mechanism described above, what you want to do is adding an event listener to the `submit` event of the form via `.addEventListener()` instead of the `onsubmit` attribute. This way you'll receive an `event` object as argument of the event handler function with which you can prevent the form submission.

Example:

```js
const myForm = document.querySelector('form'); // or '#myform', etc...

// define the event handler function
function onFormSubmission(event) {
  const fields = Array.from(event.target.elements);
  const allValid = fields.every(field => field.reportValidity()); 
  if (!allValid) {
    event.preventDefault(); // stop form submission
    return;
  }
  event.target.innerHTML = '<div class="loading"></div>';
}

// add an event listener that fires on submission
myForm.addEventListener('submit', onFormSubmission);
```

```html
<form id="myform" action="path/to/backend/script.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/formdata" novalidate>
  <input type="text" name="foo" placeholder="I am required!" required>
  <hr>
  <button type="submit">Submit form</button>
</form>
```

*EDIT*

Sorry, I missed to add the part that displays the loading information/element. Added (although you won't really see it because if all required fields are filled, the form will be submitted which results in a page refresh. You'd need something like XHR or similiar but that's not the scope of the question).

Comment: Awesome, David. I've figured it out with your code. Thanks a lot, man, I appreciate your time!!